# If $ a_n $ is bounded below and does not have a minimum then for every subsequence of $ a_n $ : $ \lim\limits_{n→∞} \{ a_{n_k} \} = \inf \{ a_n \} $

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I'm having difficulties trying to prove this proposition :

> If a sequence $ a_n $ is bounded below and does not have a minimum then for every subsequence of $ a_n $ it follows that $ \lim\limits_{n→∞} \{ a_{n_k} \} = \inf \{ a_n \} $.

I'm not sure I fully understand the proposition either.

If for every subsequence $ \lim\limits_{n→∞} \{ a_{n_k} \} = \inf \{ a_n \} $ does this implies that the sequence $ a_n $ is decreasing?

What is the strategy here to prove the proposition?

Comment: I think that you have not copied the exercise correctly, since the result is wrong. Also, a minor point: $\lim_{n\to\infty}\{a_{n_k}\}$ should probably be $\lim_{k\to\infty}\{a_{n_k}\}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proposition is false. Just consider the sequence $\{a_n\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ made by $a_n=n+1$ if n is even and $a_n=\frac{1}{n}$ if n is odd. It is clear that $0=\inf\{a_n|n\in \mathbb{N}\}$ because $a_n \ge 0$ for every n and you can get "as near as you want" to $0$,you just need to find an $n\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\frac{1}{n}\le \epsilon$,possible for every $\epsilon>0$. But if you consider the subsequence $n_k=2k $  (you take al the even indexes) it is clear $x_{n_k}\rightarrow +\infty$ for $n_k \rightarrow +\infty$.
It is not even true what you said about the fact that $a_n$ is decreasing, because the limit is just a matter related to the "last" terms.In other words, if you choose a finite number n,you can the the sequence $b_i$ made by the terms of $a_n$ for $n\ge i$ and you'll see that the limit of $b_n$ is the same of $a_n$ (if the limit of $a_n$ exists). To have an example that satisifes your hypotesis: $a_n=\frac{1}{n}$ and $b_n=n$ for $0 \le n<10$ and $b_n=a_{n-10}$ for $n \ge 10$. $b_n $ is non decreasing but is bounded below and has limit 0. It also holds that every subsuccession of $b_n$ has limit 0 because subsuccession of $a_n$.

Comment: The example you provided was very clear and helpful, thanks Nicolò. I need to alert my Real Analysis teacher that the proposition he wrote in his notes is wrong!